# What is meant with this VLOOKUP query

Tags: excel

I have an excel and in one column there is a VLOOKUP query and I dont know what a special part means.

```
=IF(NOW() > (VLOOKUP(C6;'MYWorksheet'!T:AD;11;0)+1,8558);"LAT Passed"; (NOW()-VLOOKUP(C6;'MYWorksheet'!T:AD;11;0))/0,1875)
```

C6 = Time like 09:00
'MYWorksheet'!T:AD;11 = DateTime like 23.06.2023 14:00

I understand the IF part, the VLOOKUP but what I don't understand is what does **'+1,8558'** and **'/0,1875`** means.

Can anybody help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date/Times have values rather than what you normally see as a date/time.
Here's a simple example of what that entails:

[image: excample]

As for the 0,1875 (if that's a decimal number, not a thousand separator), that's the same as 4,5 hours. 1,8558 is ~44,54 hours

Why the person who made the formula used those seemingly arbitrary numbers, I don't know..

Comment: Once you have worked out the reason, I suggest you change them to be more understandable to whoever comes after you, E.g. 12/64 might be meaningful, or cos(79.19/(180/pi()) if 79.19 is the latitude of a relevant location.

Comment: Yeah, context or something more readable/understandable is handy for people who aren't in the loop.